# How to refer to the space in which a copied object will be pasted on in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to know if there is a concrete way to refer to the space a specific object I copied will take up when I paste it. Let me give you the context: I have a worksheet from which I can copy a colored 3x3 matrix, and I want to paste it in another worksheet. In the destination worksheet, I know that the space that my colored matrix will take up is 3x3 cells. 
Say for example that I select to paste my matrix in the range `A1:C3`, but it turns out that there's already another matrix pasted in **a part** of this range, for example, there's another matrix currently pasted in the range `C3:E5`. Since the range `A1:C3` and `C3:E5` overlap in the cell `C3`, I want to avoid this and tell the user that he can't paste the currently copied matrix in `A1:C3` because it would be overlapping with another matrix that's already pasted in a part of that range. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you could explain exactly how the copying and pasting locations are selected.  If you have code, you should include that in your post.